# org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist

Tags: hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop and was doing a wordcount program in CDH 5.8.
But while I was trying to import `org.apache.haddop.conf`, I couldn't find this package.

I have added hadoop-core.jar (client 0.20) there I also I can see this module is not there.

I dont know what is the issue how to resolve and make it available.

Could anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `org.apache.haddop.conf` you need to add `hadoop-common-x.y.z.jar` to the project's build path.

To develop a Hadoop application in Eclipse you will need to add the following jars too:

`hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-x.y.z.jar`

`hadoop-hdfs-x.y.z.jar`